# Connect to Advantage Database .add in Visual Studio .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, advantage-database-server

I'm using Visual Studio .net and would like to make a simple web application using MVC.  However, I am having an extremely difficult time finding good documentation on connecting to an Advantage Database.  I've installed `Advantage.Data.Provider` and tried to connect using the example connection strings but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried to dumb it down to see if I can even connect and created a console app exactly how the example here works.
https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage10/index.html?dotnet_quick_start.htm

But I get an exception :

> "System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding
> 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'"

The only solutions I've found have led me to using System.Text.Encoding which I can't even get the app to recognize after loading the NuGet package.

I'd love a simple tutorial on a getting any .net connection string to work.

Comment: May be try using the EF: https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage10/index.html?dotnet_create_an_entity_model.htm

Answer (score 0):

try to download and install this 
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspxKey=20&Release=19&Product=12&Platform=11, 
I was in the same situation yesterday, and it unlocked me !